# Flutter using flutter_native_splash background image is stretched to fill

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen for my flutter app using flutter_native_splash and i have image 1024x1024 that i want to use as background and make it so the height always matches the height of the screen but when it comes to width to have hidden overflow instead of trying to fit the sides creating squashed image on the sides.

I've tried both setting the image as background_image and as image and then play with the gravity but either way it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android, and which version?  The `android_gravity` only applies to the `image` property, not the `background_image` property, which is always stretched.  Android 12+ does not support any background image.